# How to directly use header files without declaring .cpp in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, I've .h files and all the functions are implemented directly on the header files(no .cpp files corresponding to the .h file) but when I try to use them in main.cpp compiler throws "error LNK2001" (unresolved external symbol). Actually I'm using VCG Library ([library link](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/~cignoni/newvcglib/html/index.html)) and they have no .cpp files against .h files and in documentation they told to directly use the header files but it seems to be not working in Visual Studio 2010.

Note: I've seen some similar question has been asked before but they don't have the answer I need, so I posted it again.

Comment: What is the undefined symbol?

Comment: have you added VCG's lib directory to Visual Studio's linker settings?

Comment: Mesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall vcg::ply::PlyFile::Open(char const *,int)" (?Open@PlyFile@ply@vcg@@QAEHPBDH@Z)

Seems like the functions that are defined in header files are not getting linked with Mesh.exe file

Comment: @ Boumbles : Yes, in Project->Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories

Comment: @ Boumbles: VCG don't have .lib files, the class and functions are directly implemented in header files

Comment: this linker error suggests that you're calling the function Open without having a definition of it anywhere. I assume this is defined in some header file as you've said there are no implementation files or binaries. You're sure you've included that file?

Comment: @Boumbles : yes, I've included them, even tried with their example app, same error message for every function I try to call.In their website they said : "VCG Lib is mostly made of header files (and its core part it's only header files). Just download the tarball from here and uncompress it in a folder, e.g. named vcg, inside you compiler "include" directory. Afterwards, you have to just include the file you need."

Comment: Mostly, not exclusively. There are `.cpp` files in there, look for them.

Comment: Got it working without the .cpp ; thanks for the suggestions.